# Makefile in C programing issues getting to work

Tags: c, makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -o 
LDFLAGS = -lm 

OBJS = stack.o main.o

a.out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean: 
    rm $(OBJS)
```

This is my Makefile for this C program. I have a stack.c file and a main.c file. It is generating a main.o but it will not generate stack.o like I need it to. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is what it prints out when I attempt to run the program.

```
gcc -o    -c -o stack.o stack.c
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'stack.o' failed
make: *** [stack.o] Error 1
```

I expected this program to create object files for main.c and stack.c. It only created one for main.c.

Comment: Where on earth did you get `CFLAGS = -o` from? That cannot work, except by accident.

Comment: Probably `CFLAGS = -o` -> `CFLAGS = -O`. It's certainly a typo.

Comment: the teacher posted an old make file with that in it. i took it  out and it worked. I don't know how to run the program now though @rici

Comment: Run it with `./a.out`. This should be somewhere in your learning material

Comment: First learn to compile without a `Makefile`, and only then use a `Makefile` to ease the process.

Comment: A reasonable starting place for CFLAGS if you're using gcc is `-Wall -Og -ggdb`. `-Wall`, despite its name, produces a minimum set of warning messages; many like to use `-Wextra` as well. `-Og -ggdb` provides the best debugging experience if you use gdb to debug; `-Og` allows optimisations but not ones which will confuse the debugger, and `-ggdb` includes debugging information tuned to gdb's needs.

Comment: `gcc -o    -c -o stack.o stack.c` s very likely trying to create the output file `-c`, since `-c` is the first string after `-o`.  In any case, this command is incorrect.  You certainly do not want `-o` in CFLAGS.

Answer (score 1):

So here is what is happening:

`Make` attempts to make `a.out` which is the first (default) target in your `Makefile`.  Since `a.out` depends on `stack.o main.o`, `stack.o` is first and it probably does not exist, so it is trying to make that first.

There is no recipe that you provided in the makefile for `stack.o`.  So `Make` applies a "default" recipe, which is something like

`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o stack.o stack.c`

Now here is where the trouble starts.  Your `$(CFLAGS)` is `-o`.

So now the default recipe that it tries to execute is

`gcc -o    -c -o stack.o stack.c`

Now, the compiler parses this left-to-right and says, OK, `-o` option says they want to make an executable program, this option looks for the following name, because there is supposed to be just one name for the program, which is `-c` (that is a legal name).  Then it sees Then it sees the second `-o` and it says, OK, no, they don't, the name of the program is actually `stack.o`.  Fine.  Then it sees `stack.c` and compiles that to an object file (which goes fine), then it tries to load that as an executable `stack.o` and that is a problem because there is no `main()` in `stack.c`.

This is an exact explanation of what goes wrong.

You should now be able to figure out how to fix it so it works OK.  Since you are a beginner, I will leave it for you to learn.  Let me know if you can't figure it out in the comments.